# Any way to get around BigQuery's table limit of 1000?

Tags: google-bigquery

Seems like a 1000 table limit happens and we have to start deleting old tables.

Any way we can get an increase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a hard limit on tables in a dataset at present.  They can definitely have more than 1000 tables.  You may be having problems getting a full list of them.

- If you are using the API directly to list tables, you'll need to page through the results using the [nextPageToken](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/list#nextPageToken) if you have more than 1000 tables in a dataset.
- If you are using bq, you can list more than 1000 tables by running `bq ls -n 2000 <DATASET_ID>` to list 2000 tables, for example.
- Our web UI will display up to the first 10000 tables in a dataset.

Comment: You can also query the dataset metadata to see all the tables: Select * from YOURDATASET.__TABLES__